# How to make a large table fit on a single landscape-mode page?

Tags: tables

I have this example table: how can I make it fit on the page?

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,chapter=Title,section=Title, subsection=Title, subsubsection=Title, subsubsubsection=Title,english,brazil]{abntex2} 
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      
\usepackage{lastpage}            
\usepackage{indentfirst}         
\usepackage{color}               
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}              
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}    
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!] \centering 
\caption{\textit{Biological results}}
\textit{This table provides unit root test results for x, c, v,v, as well as forecast predicted errors  using sample period December 1234-May 2016.}:  

\label{} 
\scriptsize 

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3}  D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3}} 
\hline 
\hline 

\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$A (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$C  (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$S  (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$S  (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$E  (\tau)'s$}} \\

\\[-1.8ex]\hline 

\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 

 \beta8 = 0.05 &-0.038a45 & 0.894a45 & -0.040a45 & -0.005 & -0.052a45 & -0.244 & -0.056a45 & 0.313 & -0.048a45 & -0.555 \\
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.043;-0.033)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.221;1.567)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.051;-0.029)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.830;0.820)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.061;-0.042)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.834;1.346)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.065;-0.047)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.630;1.257)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.057;-0.040)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.115;1.006)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.1 &-0.029a45 & 0.354 & -0.028a45 & 0.370  & -0.040a45 & 0.120 & -0.039a45 & -0.379 & -0.037a45 & -0.536 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.035;-0.023)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.617;1.326)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.033;-0.023)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.791;1.532)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.046;-0.033)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.839;1.079)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.046;-0.031)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.547;0.790)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.045;-0.030)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.776;0.705)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.15 &-0.021a45 & -0.088 & -0.025a45& 0.391 & -0.033a45 & -0.130 & -0.032a45 & -0.297 & -0.028a45 & 0.333 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.025;-0.018)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.724;0.547)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.029;-0.020)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.609;1.391)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.039;-0.028)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.871;0.610)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.040;-0.025)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.053;0.459)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.034;-0.022)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.617;1.284)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.2 &-0.019a45 & -0.199 & -0.018a45 & 0.330 & -0.026a45 & 0.605 & -0.023a45 & -1.001^{*} & -0.023a45 & 0.023 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.023;-0.016)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.813;0.415)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.022;-0.015)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.402;1.062)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.031;-0.021)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.210;1.421)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.029;-0.018)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.873;-0.129)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.028;-0.017)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.003;1.050)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.25 &-0.016a45 & -0.372 & -0.016a45 & 0.393 & -0.021a45 & 0.188 & -0.018a45 & -0.527 & -0.017a45 & -0.321 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.020;-0.013)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.068;0.324)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.019;-0.012)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.374;1.160)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.025;-0.016)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.615;0.991)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.024;-0.013)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.386;0.332)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.022;-0.012)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.984;0.342)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  

%\multicolumn{1}{c(-0.022;-0.012)}

\beta8 = 0.3 &-0.013a45 & -0.205 & -0.012a45 & 0.569 & -0.018a45 & 0.289 & -0.016a45 & -0.455 & -0.013a45 & -0.602 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.017;-0.010)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.890;0.481)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.015;-0.009)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.164;1.301)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.023;-0.013)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.478;1.056)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.020;-0.011)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.187;0.278)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.018;-0.008)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.225;0.020)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.35 &-0.009a45 & -0.452 & -0.010a45 & 0.664 & -0.013a45 & -0.003 & -0.011a45 & -0.403 & -0.009a45 & -0.655a45 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.307;0.403)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.007)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.019;1.346)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.018;-0.008)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.519;0.513)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.015;-0.006)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.172;0.365)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.004)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.181;-0.129)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.4 &-0.006a45 & -0.520 & -0.007a45 & 0.471 & -0.009a45 & -0.107 & -0.006a45 & -0.756^{*} & -0.005a45 & -0.849a45 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.010;-0.002)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.373;0.334)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.010;-0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.222;1.164)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.004)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.792;0.578)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.010;-0.002)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.469;-0.044)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.009;-0.001)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.552;-0.146)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.45 &-0.0003 & -0.470 & -0.004a45 & 0.355 & -0.003 & 0.005 & -0.002 & -0.793^{*} & -0.003 & -0.922a45 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.004;0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.270;0.330)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.007;-0.001)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.246;0.957)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.008;0.001)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.630;0.641)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.006;0.002)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.517;-0.069)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.007;0.001)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.634;-0.210)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.5 &0.002 & -0.580 & -0.0004 & -0.256 & 0.001 & 0.020 & 0.003 & -0.675 & -0.0004 & -0.898a45 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.002;0.006)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.382;0.223)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.004;0.003)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.877;0.365)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.003;0.006)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.628;0.668)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.001;0.007)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.382;0.031)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.004;0.003)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.522;-0.275)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.55 &0.005a45 & -0.744 & 0.002 & -0.033 & 0.003 & 0.017 & 0.006a45 & -0.677^{*} & 0.004^{*} & -0.406 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.001;0.009)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.559;0.071)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.001;0.006)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.800;0.734)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.002;0.010)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.345;-0.008)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.002;0.010)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.345;-0.008)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0004;0.007)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.005;0.192)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.6 &0.007a45 & -0.702^{*} & 0.005a45 & -0.078 & 0.007a45 & -0.201 & 0.009a45 & -0.529 & 0.008a45 & -0.681^{*} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.004;0.011)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.294;-0.109)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.001;0.008)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.834;0.678)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.002;0.011)}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.826;0.425)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.005;0.013)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.224;0.167)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.004;0.011)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.305;-0.057)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.65 &0.011a45 & -0.639 & 0.009a45 & -0.305 & 0.012a45 & -0.436 & 0.012a45 & -0.559 & 0.009a45 & -0.586 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.014)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.298;0.021)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.006;0.012)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.016;0.405)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.016)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.966;0.093)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.017)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.209;0.090)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.005;0.013)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.327;0.154)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.7 &0.013a45 & -0.634 & 0.011a45 & -0.146 & 0.016a45 & -0.247 & 0.017a45 & -1.068a45 & 0.013a45 & -0.640^{*} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.010;0.016)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.291;0.024)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.015)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.870;0.579)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.012;0.020)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.774;0.280)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.013;0.022)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.791;-0.346)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.017)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.220;-0.061)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.75 &0.016a45 & -0.898a45 & 0.015a45 & 0.096 & 0.021a45 & -0.422 & 0.022a45 & -1.004a45 & 0.016a45 & -0.819a45 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.013;0.019)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.543;-0.252)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.012;0.018)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.560;0.753)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.017;0.025)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.085;0.241)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.017;0.026)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.741;-0.267)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.010;0.022)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.312;-0.326)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  


\beta8 = 0.8 &0.019a45 & -0.973a45 & 0.018a45 & -0.283 & 0.024a45 & -0.529^{*} & 0.027a45 & -1.036a45 & 0.022a45 & -0.868 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.016;0.023)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.475;-0.472)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.014;0.022)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.115;0.550)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.021;0.028)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.036;-0.022)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.022;0.031)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.762;-0.311)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.015;0.028)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.751;0.014)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  

\beta8 = 0.85 &0.024a45 & -1.306a45 & 0.023a45 & -0.755a45 & 0.028a45 & -0.477 & 0.032a45 & -0.793^{*} & 0.032a45 & -1.750a45 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.019;0.030)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.264;-0.347)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.018;0.028)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.342;-0.168)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.025;0.032)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.039;0.085)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.028;0.036)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.482;-0.105)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.025;0.038)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.432;-1.068)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  

\beta8 = 0.9 &0.028a45 & -1.262a45 & 0.030a45 & -1.530^{*} & 0.032a45 & -0.338a45 & 0.037a45 & -1.103a45 & 0.039a45 & -2.098a45 \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.020;0.035)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.279;-0.245)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.024;0.035)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.809;-0.252)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.027;0.036)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.502;-0.173)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.031;0.042)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.769;-0.437)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.032;0.045)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.321;-0.875)} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 

\beta8 = 0.95 &0.044a45 & -2.403a45 & 0.042a45 & -1.015 & 0.042a45 & -0.185 & 0.049a45 & -1.424 & 0.050a45 & -1.868^{*} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.034;0.054)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.731;-1.076)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.030;0.053)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.445;1.416)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.031;0.054)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.169;1.798)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.036;0.063)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.701;0.854)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.041;0.059)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.578;-0.158)} \\

\hline \\[-1.8ex] 

\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Notes:} & \multicolumn{8}{r}{^{***}Significant at the 1 percent level.} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{8}{r}{^{**}Significant at the 5 percent level.} \\ 
 & \multicolumn{8}{r}{^{*}Significant at the 10 percent level.} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Have a look at [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), as this is clearly neither a Minimal nor a Working Example. Please fix the issues, for instance `\beta` and `^{***}` are math, and should be enclosed in `\(math\)`. Also, your table is too big for a A4-page, as it doesn't fit. It is not very clear what you mean by `higher up` when in landscape-mode. Is that relative to the tables direction, or the usual up?

Comment: Your table is simple to large to be fit on A4 page. Beside this I suggest to check `threeparttable` if it is suitable for your needs and also check table construction. It is very unusual and with many errors in use of math.

Answer (score 5):

Your table is very large, and even with a lot of tweeking it can barely be made to fit (in landscape mode) on an A4-sized page.

Some suggestions:

- Use to line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of the odd-looking `\\ \hline \\[-1.8ex]` constructs
- Place the item `\beta_8` in the header cell; this allows the first column to become much narrower.
- Choose the widths of the `D`-type columns carefully. (Incidentally, what does the `a45` substring that's appended to various numbers stand for?)
- Use a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabular` environment, set `tabcolsep` to `0pt`, and let LaTeX figure out the available amounts of intercolumn whitespace.
- Make sure that the numbers in parentheses are also typeset in math mode; this matters, in particular, for the `-` symbols which should be rendered as typographic "minus" characters rather than as simple "dash" characters.
- Use a `sidewaystable` environment (provided by the `rotating` package) instead of a nested combination of `lscape` and `table` environments. That way, the table will automatically be centered vertically on the (rotated) page.
- You seem to be fond of using *italics* a lot. The effect of its overuse it that any emphasis-like impression is simply lost. The table looks better (IMHO) without *any* text-italics.
- Since there are no coefficients that are significant at either the 1% or 5% level, the footer line can be simplified considerably.

The following code implements these ideas. Note that I've reduced the preamble to the bare minimum needed to generate the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,english,brazil]{abntex2} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}           
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{$#1$}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Biological results} \label{table:bio_results} 

\scriptsize 

This table provides results of unit root tests for $x$, $c$, $v$, 
and $v$ as well as forecast prediction errors using the sample 
period December 1234--May 2016.

% Let LaTeX figure out the amount of intercolumn whitespace
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     *{3}{D..{2.6}} D..{2.3} 
     *{3}{D..{2.6}  D..{2.3}} } 
\toprule 
$\beta_8$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$A(\tau)'s$}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$C(\tau)'s$}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$S(\tau)'s$}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$S(\tau)'s$}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$E(\tau)'s$} \\

\midrule 

 $0.05$ &-0.038a45 & 0.894a45 & -0.040a45 & -0.005 & -0.052a45 & -0.244 & -0.056a45 & 0.313 & -0.048a45 & -0.555 \\
 & \mc{(-0.043;-0.033)} & \mc{(0.221;1.567)}
 & \mc{(-0.051;-0.029)} & \mc{(-0.830;0.820)} 
 & \mc{(-0.061;-0.042)}& \mc{(-1.834;1.346)} 
 & \mc{(-0.065;-0.047)} & \mc{(-0.630;1.257)}
 & \mc{(-0.057;-0.040)}& \mc{(-2.115;1.006)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}

$0.1$ &-0.029a45 & 0.354 & -0.028a45 & 0.370  & -0.040a45 & 0.120 & -0.039a45 & -0.379 & -0.037a45 & -0.536 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.035;-0.023)} & \mc{(-0.617;1.326)}
 & \mc{(-0.033;-0.023)} & \mc{(-0.791;1.532)} 
 & \mc{(-0.046;-0.033)}& \mc{(-0.839;1.079)} 
 & \mc{(-0.046;-0.031)} & \mc{(-1.547;0.790)}
 & \mc{(-0.045;-0.030)}& \mc{(-1.776;0.705)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}

$0.15$ &-0.021a45 & -0.088 & -0.025a45& 0.391 & -0.033a45 & -0.130 & -0.032a45 & -0.297 & -0.028a45 & 0.333 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.025;-0.018)} & \mc{(-0.724;0.547)}
 & \mc{(-0.029;-0.020)} & \mc{(-0.609;1.391)} 
 & \mc{(-0.039;-0.028)}& \mc{(-0.871;0.610)} 
 & \mc{(-0.040;-0.025)} & \mc{(-1.053;0.459)}
 & \mc{(-0.034;-0.022)}& \mc{(-0.617;1.284)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.2$ &-0.019a45 & -0.199 & -0.018a45 & 0.330 & -0.026a45 & 0.605 & -0.023a45 & -1.001^{*} & -0.023a45 & 0.023 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.023;-0.016)} & \mc{(-0.813;0.415)}
 & \mc{(-0.022;-0.015)} & \mc{(-0.402;1.062)} 
 & \mc{(-0.031;-0.021)}& \mc{(-0.210;1.421)} 
 & \mc{(-0.029;-0.018)} & \mc{(-1.873;-0.129)}
 & \mc{(-0.028;-0.017)}& \mc{(-1.003;1.050)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.25$ &-0.016a45 & -0.372 & -0.016a45 & 0.393 & -0.021a45 & 0.188 & -0.018a45 & -0.527 & -0.017a45 & -0.321 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.020;-0.013)} & \mc{(-1.068;0.324)}
 & \mc{(-0.019;-0.012)} & \mc{(-0.374;1.160)} 
 & \mc{(-0.025;-0.016)} & \mc{(-0.615;0.991)} 
 & \mc{(-0.024;-0.013)} & \mc{(-1.386;0.332)} 
 & \mc{(-0.022;-0.012)}& \mc{(-0.984;0.342)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}

%\multicolumn{1}{c(-0.022;-0.012)}

$0.3$ &-0.013a45 & -0.205 & -0.012a45 & 0.569 & -0.018a45 & 0.289 & -0.016a45 & -0.455 & -0.013a45 & -0.602 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.017;-0.010)} & \mc{(-0.890;0.481)}
 & \mc{(-0.015;-0.009)} & \mc{(-0.164;1.301)} 
 & \mc{(-0.023;-0.013)}& \mc{(-0.478;1.056)} 
 & \mc{(-0.020;-0.011)} & \mc{(-1.187;0.278)}
 & \mc{(-0.018;-0.008)}& \mc{(-1.225;0.020)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.35$ &-0.009a45 & -0.452 & -0.010a45 & 0.664 & -0.013a45 & -0.003 & -0.011a45 & -0.403 & -0.009a45 & -0.655a45 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.013;-0.005)} & \mc{(-1.307;0.403)}
 & \mc{(-0.013;-0.007)} & \mc{(-0.019;1.346)} 
 & \mc{(-0.018;-0.008)}& \mc{(-0.519;0.513)} 
 & \mc{(-0.015;-0.006)} & \mc{(-1.172;0.365)}
 & \mc{(-0.013;-0.004)}& \mc{(-1.181;-0.129)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.4$ &-0.006a45 & -0.520 & -0.007a45 & 0.471 & -0.009a45 & -0.107 & -0.006a45 & -0.756^{*} & -0.005a45 & -0.849a45 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.010;-0.002)} & \mc{(-1.373;0.334)}
 & \mc{(-0.010;-0.004)} & \mc{(-0.222;1.164)} 
 & \mc{(-0.013;-0.004)}& \mc{(-0.792;0.578)} 
 & \mc{(-0.010;-0.002)} & \mc{(-1.469;-0.044)}
 & \mc{(-0.009;-0.001)}& \mc{(-1.552;-0.146)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.45$ &-0.0003 & -0.470 & -0.004a45 & 0.355 & -0.003 & 0.005 & -0.002 & -0.793^{*} & -0.003 & -0.922a45 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.004;0.004)} & \mc{(-1.270;0.330)}
 & \mc{(-0.007;-0.001)} & \mc{(-0.246;0.957)} 
 & \mc{(-0.008;0.001)}& \mc{(-0.630;0.641)} 
 & \mc{(-0.006;0.002)} & \mc{(-1.517;-0.069)}
 & \mc{(-0.007;0.001)}& \mc{(-1.634;-0.210)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.5$ &0.002 & -0.580 & -0.0004 & -0.256 & 0.001 & 0.020 & 0.003 & -0.675 & -0.0004 & -0.898a45 \\ 
 & \mc{(-0.002;0.006)} & \mc{(-1.382;0.223)}
 & \mc{(-0.004;0.003)} & \mc{(-0.877;0.365)} 
 & \mc{(-0.003;0.006)}& \mc{(-0.628;0.668)} 
 & \mc{(-0.001;0.007)} & \mc{(-1.382;0.031)}
 & \mc{(-0.004;0.003)}& \mc{(-1.522;-0.275)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.55$ &0.005a45 & -0.744 & 0.002 & -0.033 & 0.003 & 0.017 & 0.006a45 & -0.677^{*} & 0.004^{*} & -0.406 \\ 
 & \mc{(0.001;0.009)} & \mc{(-1.559;0.071)}
 & \mc{(-0.001;0.006)} & \mc{(-0.800;0.734)} 
 & \mc{(0.002;0.010)}& \mc{(-1.345;-0.008)} 
 & \mc{(0.002;0.010)} & \mc{(-1.345;-0.008)}
 & \mc{(0.0004;0.007)}& \mc{(-1.005;0.192)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.6$ &0.007a45 & -0.702^{*} & 0.005a45 & -0.078 & 0.007a45 & -0.201 & 0.009a45 & -0.529 & 0.008a45 & -0.681^{*} \\ 
 & \mc{(0.004;0.011)} & \mc{(-1.294;-0.109)}
 & \mc{(0.001;0.008)} & \mc{(-0.834;0.678)} 
 & \mc{(0.002;0.011)}  & \mc{(-0.826;0.425)} 
 & \mc{(0.005;0.013)} & \mc{(-1.224;0.167)}
 & \mc{(0.004;0.011)}& \mc{(-1.305;-0.057)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.65$ &0.011a45 & -0.639 & 0.009a45 & -0.305 & 0.012a45 & -0.436 & 0.012a45 & -0.559 & 0.009a45 & -0.586 \\ 
 & \mc{(0.008;0.014)} & \mc{(-1.298;0.021)}
 & \mc{(0.006;0.012)} & \mc{(-1.016;0.405)} 
 & \mc{(0.008;0.016)}& \mc{(-0.966;0.093)} 
 & \mc{(0.008;0.017)} & \mc{(-1.209;0.090)}
 & \mc{(0.005;0.013)}& \mc{(-1.327;0.154)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.7$ &0.013a45 & -0.634 & 0.011a45 & -0.146 & 0.016a45 & -0.247 & 0.017a45 & -1.068a45 & 0.013a45 & -0.640^{*} \\ 
 & \mc{(0.010;0.016)} & \mc{(-1.291;0.024)}
 & \mc{(0.008;0.015)} & \mc{(-0.870;0.579)} 
 & \mc{(0.012;0.020)}& \mc{(-0.774;0.280)} 
 & \mc{(0.013;0.022)}& \mc{(-1.791;-0.346)}
 & \mc{(0.008;0.017)}& \mc{(-1.220;-0.061)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.75$ &0.016a45 & -0.898a45 & 0.015a45 & 0.096 & 0.021a45 & -0.422 & 0.022a45 & -1.004a45 & 0.016a45 & -0.819a45 \\ 
 & \mc{(0.013;0.019)} & \mc{(-1.543;-0.252)}
 & \mc{(0.012;0.018)} & \mc{(-0.560;0.753)} 
 & \mc{(0.017;0.025)}& \mc{(-1.085;0.241)} 
 & \mc{(0.017;0.026)} & \mc{(-1.741;-0.267)}
 & \mc{(0.010;0.022)}& \mc{(-1.312;-0.326)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}    

$0.8$ &0.019a45 & -0.973a45 & 0.018a45 & -0.283 & 0.024a45 & -0.529^{*} & 0.027a45 & -1.036a45 & 0.022a45 & -0.868 \\ 
 & \mc{(0.016;0.023)} & \mc{(-1.475;-0.472)}
 & \mc{(0.014;0.022)} & \mc{(-1.115;0.550)} 
 & \mc{(0.021;0.028)}& \mc{(-1.036;-0.022)} 
 & \mc{(0.022;0.031)} & \mc{(-1.762;-0.311)}
 & \mc{(0.015;0.028)}& \mc{(-1.751;0.014)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}

$0.85$ &0.024a45 & -1.306a45 & 0.023a45 & -0.755a45 & 0.028a45 & -0.477 & 0.032a45 & -0.793^{*} & 0.032a45 & -1.750a45 \\ 
 & \mc{(0.019;0.030)} & \mc{(-2.264;-0.347)}
 & \mc{(0.018;0.028)} & \mc{(-1.342;-0.168)} 
 & \mc{(0.025;0.032)}& \mc{(-1.039;0.085)} 
 & \mc{(0.028;0.036)}& \mc{(-1.482;-0.105)} 
 & \mc{(0.025;0.038)}& \mc{(-2.432;-1.068)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}

$0.9$ &0.028a45 & -1.262a45 & 0.030a45 & -1.530^{*} & 0.032a45 & -0.338a45 & 0.037a45 & -1.103a45 & 0.039a45 & -2.098a45 \\ 
 & \mc{(0.020;0.035)} & \mc{(-2.279;-0.245)}
 & \mc{(0.024;0.035)} & \mc{(-2.809;-0.252)} 
 & \mc{(0.027;0.036)}& \mc{(-0.502;-0.173)}
 & \mc{(0.031;0.042)} & \mc{(-1.769;-0.437)}
 & \mc{(0.032;0.045)}& \mc{(-3.321;-0.875)} \\ 
\cmidrule{1-11}

$0.95$ &0.044a45 & -2.403a45 & 0.042a45 & -1.015 & 0.042a45 & -0.185 & 0.049a45 & -1.424 & 0.050a45 & -1.868^{*} \\ 
 & \mc{(0.034;0.054)} & \mc{(-3.731;-1.076)}
 & \mc{(0.030;0.053)} & \mc{(-3.445;1.416)} 
 & \mc{(0.031;0.054)}& \mc{(-2.169;1.798)} 
 & \mc{(0.036;0.063)} & \mc{(-3.701;0.854)}
 & \mc{(0.041;0.059)}& \mc{(-3.578;-0.158)} \\

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{l}{Notes: 
    %${}^{***}$ Significant at the 1 percent level; 
    %${}^{**}$ Significant at the 5 percent level; 
     ${}^{*}$ Significant at the 10 percent level.} \\ 
\end{tabular*} 
\end{sidewaystable} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inserting a `\vspace*` does the trick, without any other changes (except inserting $-pairs to make ^ work)

*** EDIT ***

in response to Mico's comment

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,chapter=Title,section=Title, subsection=Title, subsubsection=Title, subsubsubsection=Title,english,brazil]{abntex2} 
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}      
\usepackage{lastpage}            
\usepackage{indentfirst}         
\usepackage{color}               
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}              
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}    
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[h!] \centering \vspace*{-1.5cm}
            \caption{\textit{Biological results}}
            \textit{This table provides unit root test results for x, c, v,v, as well as forecast predicted errors  using sample period December 1234-May 2016.}:  

            \label{} 
            \scriptsize 

            \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3}  D{.}{.}{-3} D{.}{.}{-3}} 
                \hline 
                \hline 

                \\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$A (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$C  (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$S  (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$S  (\tau)'s$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{$E  (\tau)'s$}} \\

                \\[-1.8ex]\hline 

                \hline 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex] 

                $\beta_8$ = 0.05 &-0.038a45 & 0.894a45 & -0.040a45 & -0.005 & -0.052a45 & -0.244 & -0.056a45 & 0.313 & -0.048a45 & -0.555 \\
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.043;-0.033)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.221;1.567)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.051;-0.029)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.830;0.820)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.061;-0.042)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.834;1.346)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.065;-0.047)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.630;1.257)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.057;-0.040)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.115;1.006)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.1 &-0.029a45 & 0.354 & -0.028a45 & 0.370  & -0.040a45 & 0.120 & -0.039a45 & -0.379 & -0.037a45 & -0.536 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.035;-0.023)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.617;1.326)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.033;-0.023)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.791;1.532)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.046;-0.033)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.839;1.079)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.046;-0.031)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.547;0.790)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.045;-0.030)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.776;0.705)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.15 &-0.021a45 & -0.088 & -0.025a45& 0.391 & -0.033a45 & -0.130 & -0.032a45 & -0.297 & -0.028a45 & 0.333 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.025;-0.018)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.724;0.547)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.029;-0.020)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.609;1.391)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.039;-0.028)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.871;0.610)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.040;-0.025)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.053;0.459)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.034;-0.022)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.617;1.284)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.2 &-0.019a45 & -0.199 & -0.018a45 & 0.330 & -0.026a45 & 0.605 & -0.023a45 & -1.001^{*} & -0.023a45 & 0.023 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.023;-0.016)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.813;0.415)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.022;-0.015)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.402;1.062)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.031;-0.021)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.210;1.421)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.029;-0.018)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.873;-0.129)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.028;-0.017)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.003;1.050)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.25 &-0.016a45 & -0.372 & -0.016a45 & 0.393 & -0.021a45 & 0.188 & -0.018a45 & -0.527 & -0.017a45 & -0.321 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.020;-0.013)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.068;0.324)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.019;-0.012)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.374;1.160)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.025;-0.016)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.615;0.991)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.024;-0.013)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.386;0.332)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.022;-0.012)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.984;0.342)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  

                %\multicolumn{1}{c(-0.022;-0.012)}

                $\beta_8$ = 0.3 &-0.013a45 & -0.205 & -0.012a45 & 0.569 & -0.018a45 & 0.289 & -0.016a45 & -0.455 & -0.013a45 & -0.602 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.017;-0.010)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.890;0.481)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.015;-0.009)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.164;1.301)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.023;-0.013)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.478;1.056)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.020;-0.011)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.187;0.278)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.018;-0.008)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.225;0.020)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.35 &-0.009a45 & -0.452 & -0.010a45 & 0.664 & -0.013a45 & -0.003 & -0.011a45 & -0.403 & -0.009a45 & -0.655a45 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.005)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.307;0.403)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.007)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.019;1.346)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.018;-0.008)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.519;0.513)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.015;-0.006)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.172;0.365)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.004)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.181;-0.129)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.4 &-0.006a45 & -0.520 & -0.007a45 & 0.471 & -0.009a45 & -0.107 & -0.006a45 & -0.756^{*} & -0.005a45 & -0.849a45 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.010;-0.002)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.373;0.334)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.010;-0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.222;1.164)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.013;-0.004)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.792;0.578)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.010;-0.002)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.469;-0.044)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.009;-0.001)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.552;-0.146)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.45 &-0.0003 & -0.470 & -0.004a45 & 0.355 & -0.003 & 0.005 & -0.002 & -0.793^{*} & -0.003 & -0.922a45 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.004;0.004)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.270;0.330)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.007;-0.001)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.246;0.957)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.008;0.001)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.630;0.641)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.006;0.002)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.517;-0.069)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.007;0.001)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.634;-0.210)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.5 &0.002 & -0.580 & -0.0004 & -0.256 & 0.001 & 0.020 & 0.003 & -0.675 & -0.0004 & -0.898a45 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.002;0.006)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.382;0.223)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.004;0.003)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.877;0.365)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.003;0.006)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.628;0.668)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.001;0.007)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.382;0.031)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.004;0.003)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.522;-0.275)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.55 &0.005a45 & -0.744 & 0.002 & -0.033 & 0.003 & 0.017 & 0.006a45 & -0.677^{*} & 0.004^{*} & -0.406 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.001;0.009)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.559;0.071)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.001;0.006)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.800;0.734)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.002;0.010)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.345;-0.008)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.002;0.010)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.345;-0.008)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.0004;0.007)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.005;0.192)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.6 &0.007a45 & -0.702^{*} & 0.005a45 & -0.078 & 0.007a45 & -0.201 & 0.009a45 & -0.529 & 0.008a45 & -0.681^{*} \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.004;0.011)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.294;-0.109)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.001;0.008)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.834;0.678)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.002;0.011)}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.826;0.425)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.005;0.013)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.224;0.167)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.004;0.011)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.305;-0.057)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.65 &0.011a45 & -0.639 & 0.009a45 & -0.305 & 0.012a45 & -0.436 & 0.012a45 & -0.559 & 0.009a45 & -0.586 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.014)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.298;0.021)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.006;0.012)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.016;0.405)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.016)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.966;0.093)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.017)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.209;0.090)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.005;0.013)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.327;0.154)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.7 &0.013a45 & -0.634 & 0.011a45 & -0.146 & 0.016a45 & -0.247 & 0.017a45 & -1.068a45 & 0.013a45 & -0.640^{*} \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.010;0.016)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.291;0.024)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.015)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.870;0.579)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.012;0.020)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.774;0.280)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.013;0.022)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.791;-0.346)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.008;0.017)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.220;-0.061)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.75 &0.016a45 & -0.898a45 & 0.015a45 & 0.096 & 0.021a45 & -0.422 & 0.022a45 & -1.004a45 & 0.016a45 & -0.819a45 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.013;0.019)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.543;-0.252)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.012;0.018)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.560;0.753)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.017;0.025)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.085;0.241)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.017;0.026)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.741;-0.267)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.010;0.022)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.312;-0.326)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  


                $\beta_8$ = 0.8 &0.019a45 & -0.973a45 & 0.018a45 & -0.283 & 0.024a45 & -0.529^{*} & 0.027a45 & -1.036a45 & 0.022a45 & -0.868 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.016;0.023)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.475;-0.472)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.014;0.022)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.115;0.550)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.021;0.028)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.036;-0.022)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.022;0.031)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.762;-0.311)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.015;0.028)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.751;0.014)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  

                $\beta_8$ = 0.85 &0.024a45 & -1.306a45 & 0.023a45 & -0.755a45 & 0.028a45 & -0.477 & 0.032a45 & -0.793^{*} & 0.032a45 & -1.750a45 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.019;0.030)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.264;-0.347)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.018;0.028)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.342;-0.168)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.025;0.032)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.039;0.085)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.028;0.036)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.482;-0.105)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.025;0.038)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.432;-1.068)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex]  

                $\beta_8$ = 0.9 &0.028a45 & -1.262a45 & 0.030a45 & -1.530^{*} & 0.032a45 & -0.338a45 & 0.037a45 & -1.103a45 & 0.039a45 & -2.098a45 \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.020;0.035)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.279;-0.245)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.024;0.035)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.809;-0.252)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.027;0.036)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-0.502;-0.173)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.031;0.042)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-1.769;-0.437)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.032;0.045)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.321;-0.875)} \\ 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex] 

                $\beta_8$ = 0.95 &0.044a45 & -2.403a45 & 0.042a45 & -1.015 & 0.042a45 & -0.185 & 0.049a45 & -1.424 & 0.050a45 & -1.868^{*} \\ 
                & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.034;0.054)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.731;-1.076)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.030;0.053)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.445;1.416)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.031;0.054)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-2.169;1.798)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.036;0.063)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.701;0.854)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(0.041;0.059)}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-3.578;-0.158)} \\

                \hline \\[-1.8ex] 

                \hline 
                \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
                \textit{Notes:} & \multicolumn{8}{r}{$^{***}$Significant at the 1 percent level.} \\ 
                & \multicolumn{8}{r}{$^{**}$Significant at the 5 percent level.} \\ 
                & \multicolumn{8}{r}{$^{*}$Significant at the 10 percent level.} \\ 
            \end{tabular} 
        \end{table} 
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better centred with the `sidewaystable` environment. I propose two solutions: one with the horizontal rules from `booktabs`, which adds some vertical padding around these rules, and simplifies the code. Another with only  rules at top and bottom, and an improved legibility of the table with `\arraystretch=1.25` and alternating background colours in rows. Also I use the `threeparttable` environment for table notes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper,chapter=Title,section=Title, subsection=Title, subsubsection=Title, subsubsubsection=Title,english,brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-post=a45}
\label{}
\scriptsize
\setlength\aboverulesep{0.35ex}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0.55ex}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\centering%
\caption{\textit{Biological results}}
\begin{threeparttable}
%
$ \begin{array}{ l*{10}{S}}%
\multicolumn {11}{c}{\textit{This table provides unit root test results for x, c, v,v, as well as forecast predicted errors using sample period December 1234--May 2016.}:}\\[1ex]
\toprule
\midrule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{A(\tau)'s} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C(\tau)'s} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{S(\tau)'s}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{S(\tau)'s}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{E(\tau)'s} \\
\midrule%
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.05 &-0.038a45 & 0.894a45 & -0.040a45 & -0.005 & -0.052a45 & -0.244 & -0.056a45 & 0.313 & -0.048a45 & -0.555 \\
 &{(-0.043;-0.033)} & {(0.221;1.567) }& {(-0.051;-0.029)} & {(-0.830;0.820)} & {(-0.061;-0.042)}& {(-1.834;1.346)} & {(-0.065;-0.047)} & {(-0.630;1.257)} & {(-0.057;-0.040)} & {(-2.115;1.006)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.1 &-0.029a45 & 0.354 & -0.028a45 & 0.370 & -0.040a45 & 0.120 & -0.039a45 & -0.379 & -0.037a45 & -0.536 \\
 & {(-0.035;-0.023)} & {(-0.617;1.326)}& {(-0.033;-0.023)} & {(-0.791;1.532)} & {(-0.046;-0.033)}& {(-0.839;1.079)} & {(-0.046;-0.031)} & {(-1.547;0.790)}& {(-0.045;-0.030)}& {(-1.776;0.705)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.15 &-0.021a45 & -0.088 & -0.025a45& 0.391 & -0.033a45 & -0.130 & -0.032a45 & -0.297 & -0.028a45 & 0.333 \\
 & {(-0.025;-0.018)} & {(-0.724;0.547)}& {(-0.029;-0.020)} & {(-0.609;1.391)} & {(-0.039;-0.028)}& {(-0.871;0.610)} & {(-0.040;-0.025)} & {(-1.053;0.459)}& {(-0.034;-0.022)}& {(-0.617;1.284)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.2 &-0.019a45 & -0.199 & -0.018a45 & 0.330 & -0.026a45 & 0.605 & -0.023a45 & -1.001\tnote{*} & -0.023a45 & 0.023 \\
 & {(-0.023;-0.016)} & {(-0.813;0.415)}& {(-0.022;-0.015)} & {(-0.402;1.062)} & {(-0.031;-0.021)}& {(-0.210;1.421)} & {(-0.029;-0.018)} & {(-1.873;-0.129)}& {(-0.028;-0.017)}& {(-1.003;1.050)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.25 &-0.016a45 & -0.372 & -0.016a45 & 0.393 & -0.021a45 & 0.188 & -0.018a45 & -0.527 & -0.017a45 & -0.321 \\
 & {(-0.020;-0.013)} & {(-1.068;0.324)}& {(-0.019;-0.012)} & {(-0.374;1.160)} & {(-0.025;-0.016)} & {(-0.615;0.991)} & {(-0.024;-0.013)} & {(-1.386;0.332)} & {(-0.022;-0.012)}& {(-0.984;0.342)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.3 &-0.013a45 & -0.205 & -0.012a45 & 0.569 & -0.018a45 & 0.289 & -0.016a45 & -0.455 & -0.013a45 & -0.602 \\
 & {(-0.017;-0.010)} & {(-0.890;0.481)}& {(-0.015;-0.009)} & {(-0.164;1.301)} & {(-0.023;-0.013)}& {(-0.478;1.056)} & {(-0.020;-0.011)} & {(-1.187;0.278)}& {(-0.018;-0.008)}& {(-1.225;0.020)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.35 &-0.009a45 & -0.452 & -0.010a45 & 0.664 & -0.013a45 & -0.003 & -0.011a45 & -0.403 & -0.009a45 & -0.655a45 \\
 & {(-0.013;-0.005)} & {(-1.307;0.403)}& {(-0.013;-0.007)} & {(-0.019;1.346)} & {(-0.018;-0.008)}& {(-0.519;0.513)} & {(-0.015;-0.006)} & {(-1.172;0.365)}& {(-0.013;-0.004)}& {(-1.181;-0.129)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.4 &-0.006a45 & -0.520 & -0.007a45 & 0.471 & -0.009a45 & -0.107 & -0.006a45 & -0.756\tnote{*} & -0.005a45 & -0.849a45 \\
 & {(-0.010;-0.002)} & {(-1.373;0.334)}& {(-0.010;-0.004)} & {(-0.222;1.164)} & {(-0.013;-0.004)}& {(-0.792;0.578)} & {(-0.010;-0.002)} & {(-1.469;-0.044)}& {(-0.009;-0.001)}& {(-1.552;-0.146)}\\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.45 &-0.0003 & -0.470 & -0.004a45 & 0.355 & -0.003 & 0.005 & -0.002 & -0.793\tnote{*} & -0.003 & -0.922a45 \\
 & {(-0.004;0.004)} & {(-1.270;0.330)}& {(-0.007;-0.001)} & {(-0.246;0.957)} & {(-0.008;0.001)}& {(-0.630;0.641)} & {(-0.006;0.002)} & {(-1.517;-0.069)}& {(-0.007;0.001)}& {(-1.634;-0.210)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.5 &0.002 & -0.580 & -0.0004 & -0.256 & 0.001 & 0.020 & 0.003 & -0.675 & -0.0004 & -0.898a45 \\
 & {(-0.002;0.006)} & {(-1.382;0.223)}& {(-0.004;0.003)} & {(-0.877;0.365)} & {(-0.003;0.006)}& {(-0.628;0.668)} & {(-0.001;0.007)} & {(-1.382;0.031)}& {(-0.004;0.003)}& {(-1.522;-0.275)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.55 &0.005a45 & -0.744 & 0.002 & -0.033 & 0.003 & 0.017 & 0.006a45 & -0.677\tnote{*} & 0.004\tnote{*} & -0.406 \\
 & {(0.001;0.009)} & {(-1.559;0.071)}& {(-0.001;0.006)} & {(-0.800;0.734)} & {(0.002;0.010)}& {(-1.345;-0.008)} & {(0.002;0.010)} & {(-1.345;-0.008)}& {(0.0004;0.007)}& {(-1.005;0.192)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.6 &0.007a45 & -0.702\tnote{*} & 0.005a45 & -0.078 & 0.007a45 & -0.201 & 0.009a45 & -0.529 & 0.008a45 & -0.681\tnote{*} \\
 & {(0.004;0.011)} & {(-1.294;-0.109)}& {(0.001;0.008)} & {(-0.834;0.678)} & {(0.002;0.011)} & {(-0.826;0.425)} & {(0.005;0.013)} & {(-1.224;0.167)}& {(0.004;0.011)}& {(-1.305;-0.057)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.65 &0.011a45 & -0.639 & 0.009a45 & -0.305 & 0.012a45 & -0.436 & 0.012a45 & -0.559 & 0.009a45 & -0.586 \\
 & {(0.008;0.014)} & {(-1.298;0.021)}& {(0.006;0.012)} & {(-1.016;0.405)} & {(0.008;0.016)}& {(-0.966;0.093)} & {(0.008;0.017)} & {(-1.209;0.090)}& {(0.005;0.013)}& {(-1.327;0.154)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.7 &0.013a45 & -0.634 & 0.011a45 & -0.146 & 0.016a45 & -0.247 & 0.017a45 & -1.068a45 & 0.013a45 & -0.640\tnote{*} \\
 & {(0.010;0.016)} & {(-1.291;0.024)}& {(0.008;0.015)} & {(-0.870;0.579)} & {(0.012;0.020)}& {(-0.774;0.280)} & {(0.013;0.022)}& {(-1.791;-0.346)}& {(0.008;0.017)}& {(-1.220;-0.061)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.75 &0.016a45 & -0.898a45 & 0.015a45 & 0.096 & 0.021a45 & -0.422 & 0.022a45 & -1.004a45 & 0.016a45 & -0.819a45 \\
 & {(0.013;0.019)} & {(-1.543;-0.252)}& {(0.012;0.018)} & {(-0.560;0.753)} & {(0.017;0.025)}& {(-1.085;0.241)} & {(0.017;0.026)} & {(-1.741;-0.267)}& {(0.010;0.022)}& {(-1.312;-0.326)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.8 &0.019a45 & -0.973a45 & 0.018a45 & -0.283 & 0.024a45 & -0.529\tnote{*} & 0.027a45 & -1.036a45 & 0.022a45 & -0.868 \\
 & {(0.016;0.023)} & {(-1.475;-0.472)}& {(0.014;0.022)} & {(-1.115;0.550)} & {(0.021;0.028)}& {(-1.036;-0.022)} & {(0.022;0.031)} & {(-1.762;-0.311)}& {(0.015;0.028)}& {(-1.751;0.014)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.85 &0.024a45 & -1.306a45 & 0.023a45 & -0.755a45 & 0.028a45 & -0.477 & 0.032a45 & -0.793\tnote{*} & 0.032a45 & -1.750a45 \\
 & {(0.019;0.030)} & {(-2.264;-0.347)}& {(0.018;0.028)} & {(-1.342;-0.168)} & {(0.025;0.032)}& {(-1.039;0.085)} & {(0.028;0.036)}& {(-1.482;-0.105)} & {(0.025;0.038)}& {(-2.432;-1.068)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.9 &0.028a45 & -1.262a45 & 0.030a45 & -1.530\tnote{*} & 0.032a45 & -0.338a45 & 0.037a45 & -1.103a45 & 0.039a45 & -2.098a45 \\
 & {(0.020;0.035)} & {(-2.279;-0.245)}& {(0.024;0.035)} & {(-2.809;-0.252)} & {(0.027;0.036)}& {(-0.502;-0.173)}& {(0.031;0.042)} & {(-1.769;-0.437)}& {(0.032;0.045)}& {(-3.321;-0.875)} \\
\midrule

\beta8 = 0.95 &0.044a45 & -2.403a45 & 0.042a45 & -1.015 & 0.042a45 & -0.185 & 0.049a45 & -1.424 & 0.050a45 & -1.868\tnote{*} \\
 & {(0.034;0.054)} & {(-3.731;-1.076)}& {(0.030;0.053)} & {(-3.445;1.416)} & {(0.031;0.054)}& {(-2.169;1.798)} & {(0.036;0.063)} & {(-3.701;0.854)}& {(0.041;0.059)}& {(-3.578;-0.158)} \\
\midrule
\bottomrule%
\end{array} $
\begin{tablenotes}[para]\smallskip\raggedright
  \item[***] Significant at the 1 percent level.
  \item[**]Significant at the 5 percent level.
  \item[*]Significant at the 10 percent level.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-post=a45}
\label{}
\scriptsize
\setlength\aboverulesep{0.35ex}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{0.25em}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0.55ex}
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
 \centering%
\caption{\textit{Biological results}}
\begin{threeparttable}
%
$ \begin{array}{l*{10}{S}}%
\multicolumn {11}{c}{\textit{This table provides unit root test results for x, c, v,v, as well as forecast predicted errors using sample period December 1234-May 2016.}:}\\[1ex]
\toprule
\midrule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{A(τ)'s} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{C(τ)'s} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{S(τ)'s} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{S(τ)'s} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E(τ)'s} \\
\midrule%
\midrule
\addlinespace[-\dimexpr\belowrulesep+\lightrulewidth]
\rowcolor{Lavender} \beta8 = 0.05 &-0.038a45 & 0.894a45 & -0.040a45 & -0.005 & -0.052a45 & -0.244 & -0.056a45 & 0.313 & -0.048a45 & -0.555 \\
 \rowcolor{Lavender}&{(-0.043;-0.033)} & {(0.221;1.567)}& {(-0.051;-0.029)} & {(-0.830;0.820)} & {(-0.061;-0.042)}& {(-1.834;1.346)} & {(-0.065;-0.047)} & {(-0.630;1.257)}& {(-0.057;-0.040)}& {(-2.115;1.006)} \\

 \beta8 = 0.1 &-0.029a45 & 0.354 & -0.028a45 & 0.370 & -0.040a45 & 0.120 & -0.039a45 & -0.379 & -0.037a45 & -0.536 \\
 & {(-0.035;-0.023)} & {(-0.617;1.326)}& {(-0.033;-0.023)} & {(-0.791;1.532)} & {(-0.046;-0.033)}& {(-0.839;1.079)} & {(-0.046;-0.031)} & {(-1.547;0.790)}& {(-0.045;-0.030)}& {(-1.776;0.705)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender}\beta8 = 0.15 &-0.021a45 & -0.088 & -0.025a45& 0.391 & -0.033a45 & -0.130 & -0.032a45 & -0.297 & -0.028a45 & 0.333 \\
\rowcolor{Lavender} & {(-0.025;-0.018)} & {(-0.724;0.547)}& {(-0.029;-0.020)} & {(-0.609;1.391)} & {(-0.039;-0.028)}& {(-0.871;0.610)} & {(-0.040;-0.025)} & {(-1.053;0.459)}& {(-0.034;-0.022)}& {(-0.617;1.284)} \\

\beta8 = 0.2 &-0.019a45 & -0.199 & -0.018a45 & 0.330 & -0.026a45 & 0.605 & -0.023a45 & -1.001\tnote{*} & -0.023a45 & 0.023 \\
 & {(-0.023;-0.016)} & {(-0.813;0.415)}& {(-0.022;-0.015)} & {(-0.402;1.062)} & {(-0.031;-0.021)}& {(-0.210;1.421)} & {(-0.029;-0.018)} & {(-1.873;-0.129)}& {(-0.028;-0.017)}& {(-1.003;1.050)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender}\beta8 = 0.25 &-0.016a45 & -0.372 & -0.016a45 & 0.393 & -0.021a45 & 0.188 & -0.018a45 & -0.527 & -0.017a45 & -0.321 \\
\rowcolor{Lavender}& {(-0.020;-0.013)} & {(-1.068;0.324)}& {(-0.019;-0.012)} & {(-0.374;1.160)} & {(-0.025;-0.016)} & {(-0.615;0.991)} & {(-0.024;-0.013)} & {(-1.386;0.332)} & {(-0.022;-0.012)}& {(-0.984;0.342)} \\

 \beta8 = 0.3 &-0.013a45 & -0.205 & -0.012a45 & 0.569 & -0.018a45 & 0.289 & -0.016a45 & -0.455 & -0.013a45 & -0.602 \\
 & {(-0.017;-0.010)} & {(-0.890;0.481)}& {(-0.015;-0.009)} & {(-0.164;1.301)} & {(-0.023;-0.013)}& {(-0.478;1.056)} & {(-0.020;-0.011)} & {(-1.187;0.278)}& {(-0.018;-0.008)}& {(-1.225;0.020)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender}\beta8 = 0.35 &-0.009a45 & -0.452 & -0.010a45 & 0.664 & -0.013a45 & -0.003 & -0.011a45 & -0.403 & -0.009a45 & -0.655a45 \\
\rowcolor{Lavender} & {(-0.013;-0.005)} & {(-1.307;0.403)}& {(-0.013;-0.007)} & {(-0.019;1.346)} & {(-0.018;-0.008)}& {(-0.519;0.513)} & {(-0.015;-0.006)} & {(-1.172;0.365)}& {(-0.013;-0.004)}& {(-1.181;-0.129)} \\

\beta8 = 0.4 &-0.006a45 & -0.520 & -0.007a45 & 0.471 & -0.009a45 & -0.107 & -0.006a45 & -0.756\tnote{*} & -0.005a45 & -0.849a45 \\
 & {(-0.010;-0.002)} & {(-1.373;0.334)}& {(-0.010;-0.004)} & {(-0.222;1.164)} & {(-0.013;-0.004)}& {(-0.792;0.578)} & {(-0.010;-0.002)} & {(-1.469;-0.044)}& {(-0.009;-0.001)}& {(-1.552;-0.146)}\\

\rowcolor{Lavender}\beta8 = 0.45 &-0.0003 & -0.470 & -0.004a45 & 0.355 & -0.003 & 0.005 & -0.002 & -0.793\tnote{*} & -0.003 & -0.922a45 \\
\rowcolor{Lavender} & {(-0.004;0.004)} & {(-1.270;0.330)}& {(-0.007;-0.001)} & {(-0.246;0.957)} & {(-0.008;0.001)}& {(-0.630;0.641)} & {(-0.006;0.002)} & {(-1.517;-0.069)}& {(-0.007;0.001)}& {(-1.634;-0.210)} \\

\beta8 = 0.5 &0.002 & -0.580 & -0.0004 & -0.256 & 0.001 & 0.020 & 0.003 & -0.675 & -0.0004 & -0.898a45 \\
 & {(-0.002;0.006)} & {(-1.382;0.223)}& {(-0.004;0.003)} & {(-0.877;0.365)} & {(-0.003;0.006)}& {(-0.628;0.668)} & {(-0.001;0.007)} & {(-1.382;0.031)}& {(-0.004;0.003)}& {(-1.522;-0.275)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender}\beta8 = 0.55 &0.005a45 & -0.744 & 0.002 & -0.033 & 0.003 & 0.017 & 0.006a45 & -0.677\tnote{*} & 0.004\tnote{*} & -0.406 \\
\rowcolor{Lavender} & {(0.001;0.009)} & {(-1.559;0.071)}& {(-0.001;0.006)} & {(-0.800;0.734)} & {(0.002;0.010)}& {(-1.345;-0.008)} & {(0.002;0.010)} & {(-1.345;-0.008)}& {(0.0004;0.007)}& {(-1.005;0.192)} \\

\beta8 = 0.6 &0.007a45 & -0.702\tnote{*} & 0.005a45 & -0.078 & 0.007a45 & -0.201 & 0.009a45 & -0.529 & 0.008a45 & -0.681\tnote{*} \\
 & {(0.004;0.011)} & {(-1.294;-0.109)}& {(0.001;0.008)} & {(-0.834;0.678)} & {(0.002;0.011)} & {(-0.826;0.425)} & {(0.005;0.013)} & {(-1.224;0.167)}& {(0.004;0.011)}& {(-1.305;-0.057)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender}\beta8 = 0.65 &0.011a45 & -0.639 & 0.009a45 & -0.305 & 0.012a45 & -0.436 & 0.012a45 & -0.559 & 0.009a45 & -0.586 \\
 \rowcolor{Lavender}& {(0.008;0.014)} & {(-1.298;0.021)}& {(0.006;0.012)} & {(-1.016;0.405)} & {(0.008;0.016)}& {(-0.966;0.093)} & {(0.008;0.017)} & {(-1.209;0.090)}& {(0.005;0.013)}& {(-1.327;0.154)} \\

\beta8 = 0.7 &0.013a45 & -0.634 & 0.011a45 & -0.146 & 0.016a45 & -0.247 & 0.017a45 & -1.068a45 & 0.013a45 & -0.640\tnote{*} \\
 & {(0.010;0.016)} & {(-1.291;0.024)}& {(0.008;0.015)} & {(-0.870;0.579)} & {(0.012;0.020)}& {(-0.774;0.280)} & {(0.013;0.022)}& {(-1.791;-0.346)}& {(0.008;0.017)}& {(-1.220;-0.061)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender} \beta8 = 0.75 &0.016a45 & -0.898a45 & 0.015a45 & 0.096 & 0.021a45 & -0.422 & 0.022a45 & -1.004a45 & 0.016a45 & -0.819a45 \\
\rowcolor{Lavender} & {(0.013;0.019)} & {(-1.543;-0.252)}& {(0.012;0.018)} & {(-0.560;0.753)} & {(0.017;0.025)}& {(-1.085;0.241)} & {(0.017;0.026)} & {(-1.741;-0.267)}& {(0.010;0.022)}& {(-1.312;-0.326)} \\

  \beta8 = 0.8 & 0.019a45 & -0.973a45 & 0.018a45 & -0.283 & 0.024a45 & -0.529\tnote{*} & 0.027a45 & -1.036a45 & 0.022a45 & -0.868 \\
 & {(0.016;0.023)} & {(-1.475;-0.472)}& {(0.014;0.022)} & {(-1.115;0.550)} & {(0.021;0.028)}& {(-1.036;-0.022)} & {(0.022;0.031)} & {(-1.762;-0.311)}& {(0.015;0.028)}& {(-1.751;0.014)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender} \beta8 = 0.85 & 0.024a45 & -1.306a45 & 0.023a45 & -0.755a45 & 0.028a45 & -0.477 & 0.032a45 & -0.793\tnote{*} & 0.032a45 & -1.750a45 \\
\rowcolor{Lavender} & {(0.019;0.030)} & {(-2.264;-0.347)}& {(0.018;0.028)} & {(-1.342;-0.168)} & {(0.025;0.032)}& {(-1.039;0.085)} & {(0.028;0.036)}& {(-1.482;-0.105)} & {(0.025;0.038)}& {(-2.432;-1.068)} \\

 \beta8 = 0.9 & 0.028a45 & -1.262a45 & 0.030a45 & -1.530\tnote{*} & 0.032a45 & -0.338a45 & 0.037a45 & -1.103a45 & 0.039a45 & -2.098a45 \\
 & {(0.020;0.035)} & {(-2.279;-0.245)}& {(0.024;0.035)} & {(-2.809;-0.252)} & {(0.027;0.036)}& {(-0.502;-0.173)}& {(0.031;0.042)} & {(-1.769;-0.437)} & {(0.032;0.045)}& {(-3.321;-0.875)} \\

\rowcolor{Lavender} \beta8 = 0.95 & 0.044a45 & -2.403a45 & 0.042a45 & -1.015 & 0.042a45 & -0.185 & 0.049a45 & -1.424 & 0.050a45 & -1.868\tnote{*} \\
\rowcolor{Lavender} & {(0.034;0.054)} & {(-3.731;-1.076)}& {(0.030;0.053)} & {(-3.445;1.416)} & {(0.031;0.054)}& {(-2.169;1.798)} & {(0.036;0.063)} & {(-3.701;0.854)}& {(0.041;0.059)}& {(-3.578;-0.158)} \\
\addlinespace[-\dimexpr\aboverulesep+\lightrulewidth]
\midrule
\bottomrule%
\end{array} $
 \begin{tablenotes}[para]\smallskip\raggedright
  \item[***]Significant at the 1 percent level.
  \item[**]Significant at the 5 percent level.
  \item[*]Significant at the 10 percent level.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Mico: Done!  I confess I shrank away from adding thousands of pairs of `$`, but I finally changed   `tabular` into `array` (enclosed in `$ $`). Not sure it's quite orthodox, but it works with some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion ...

With use of `threeparttablex`, introduction of some new macros and after reformatting (I did this only for first four rows) I obtain the following table:

[image]

(for this images are repeated first four rows so many times that it has together 19 rows).

In MWE below instead original document class I use `article` and with `geometry` package set approximately page layout as is defined by `abntex2` (which I haven't installed in my laptop). With reorganization of table and use of the introduced macros I succeed to increase table font size to `\small` and by this made it more readable and (almost) fit table in space for text (this can evaluate with showed page layout).

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,ltablex,makecell,threeparttablex}
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textbf{#1}}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape}
\newcommand{\mchead}[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{$#1$}}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

    \usepackage[margin=25mm,
                showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[font=it]{caption}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{sidewaystable}[htb]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.75}
    \small
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \caption{Biological results}
    \label{tab:addlabel }%
\emph{This table provides unit root test results for x, c, v, v, as well as forecast predicted errors using sample period December 1234-May 2016.}\vspace{-2ex}
    \setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,raggedright]\smallskip
    \item[***]  Significant at the 1  percent level.
    \item[**]   Significant at the 5  percent level.
    \item[*]    Significant at the 10 percent level.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X*{10}{S[table-format=-4.3]@{}l}@{}}
    \toprule
$\beta8$ 
    &   \mchead{A(\tau)'s} 
        &   \mchead{C(\tau)'s}
            &   \mchead{S(\tau)'s}
                &   \mchead{S(\tau)'s} 
                    &   \mchead{E(\tau)'s}                          \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
        \cmidrule(lr){10-13}\cmidrule(lr){14-17}\cmidrule(lr){18-21}
0.05    & -0.038 &a45   & 0.894 &a45    & -0.040 &a45   & -0.005 &      & -0.052 &a45 
        & -0.244 &      & -0.056&a45    & 0.313  &      & -0.048 &a45   & -0.555 &   \\
        & \mc{(-0.043;-0.033)} 
                        & \mc{(0.221;1.567)}
                                        &   \mc{(-0.051;-0.029)} 
                                                        & \mc{(-0.830;0.820)} 
                                                                        & \mc{(-0.061;-0.042)}
        & \mc{(-1.834;1.346)} 
                        & \mc{(-0.065;-0.047)} 
                                        & \mc{(-0.630;1.257)}
                                                        & \mc{(-0.057;-0.040)}
                                                                        & \mc{(-2.115;1.006)}
    \\  \addlinespace
%
0.1     &-0.029 &a45    &  0.354 &      & -0.028 & a45  &  0.370 &      & -0.040 &a45 
        & 0.120 &       & -0.039 &a45   & -0.379 &      & -0.037 &a45   & -0.536 &  \\
        & \mc{(-0.035;-0.023)} 
                        & \mc{(-0.617;1.326)}
                                        & \mc{(-0.033;-0.023)} 
                                                        & \mc{(-0.791;1.532)} 
                                                                        & \mc{(-0.046;-0.033)}
        & \mc{(-0.839;1.079)} 
                        & \mc{(-0.046;-0.031)} 
                                        & \mc{(-1.547;0.790)}
                                                        & \mc{(-0.045;-0.030)}
                                                                        & \mc{(-1.776;0.705)}
    \\  \addlinespace
%
0.05    & -0.038 &a45   & 0.894 &a45    & -0.040 &a45   & -0.005 &      & -0.052 &a45
        & -0.244 &      & -0.056&a45    & 0.313  &      & -0.048 &a45   & -0.555 &   \\
        & \mc{(-0.043;-0.033)}
                        & \mc{(0.221;1.567)}
                                        &   \mc{(-0.051;-0.029)}
                                                        & \mc{(-0.830;0.820)}
                                                                        & \mc{(-0.061;-0.042)}
        & \mc{(-1.834;1.346)}
                        & \mc{(-0.065;-0.047)}
                                        & \mc{(-0.630;1.257)}
                                                        & \mc{(-0.057;-0.040)}
                                                                        & \mc{(-2.115;1.006)}
    \\  
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
    \end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
As follows from @Bernard answer, the above solution is unnecessary complicated regarding meaning of `a45` in some cels. Considering his solution in settings `a45` to some numbers, the above table can be simplyfied as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs,ltablex,makecell,threeparttablex}
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textbf{#1}}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\itshape}
\newcommand{\mchead}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{$#1$}}}

    \usepackage[margin=25mm,
                showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage[font=it]{caption}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{sidewaystable}[htb]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.75}
    \small
\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \caption{Biological results}
    \label{tab:addlabel }%
\emph{This table provides unit root test results for x, c, v, v, as well as forecast predicted errors using sample period December 1234-May 2016.}\vspace{-2ex}
    \setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,raggedright]\smallskip
    \item[***]  Significant at the 1  percent level.
    \item[**]   Significant at the 5  percent level.
    \item[*]    Significant at the 10 percent level.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X*{10}{S[table-format=-1.3]}}
    \toprule
$\beta8$
    &   \mchead{A(\tau)'s}
        &   \mchead{C(\tau)'s}
            &   \mchead{S(\tau)'s}
                &   \mchead{S(\tau)'s}
                    &   \mchead{E(\tau)'s}                          \\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        \cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
0.05    & -0.038a45 & 0.894a45    & -0.040a45   & -0.005      & -0.052a45
        & -0.244    & -0.056a45   & 0.313       & -0.048a45   & -0.555   \\
        & {(-0.043;-0.033)}
                    & {(0.221;1.567)}
                                  & {(-0.051;-0.029)}
                                                & {(-0.830;0.820)}
                                                              & {(-0.061;-0.042)}
        & {(-1.834;1.346)}
                    & {(-0.065;-0.047)}
                                  & {(-0.630;1.257)}
                                                & {(-0.057;-0.040)}
                                                              & {(-2.115;1.006)}
    \\  \addlinespace
%
0.1     &-0.029a45    &  0.354    & -0.028a45   &  0.370      & -0.040a45
        & 0.120       & -0.039a45 & -0.379      & -0.037a45   & -0.536   \\
        & {(-0.035;-0.023)}
                      & {(-0.617;1.326)}
                                  & {(-0.033;-0.023)}
                                                & {(-0.791;1.532)}
                                                              & {(-0.046;-0.033)}
        & {(-0.839;1.079)}
                      & {(-0.046;-0.031)}
                                  & {(-1.547;0.790)}
                                                & {(-0.045;-0.030)}
                                                              & {(-1.776;0.705)}
    \\  \addlinespace
%
0.05    & -0.038a45 & 0.894a45    & -0.040a45   & -0.005      & -0.052a45
        & -0.244    & -0.056a45   & 0.313       & -0.048a45   & -0.555   \\
        & {(-0.043;-0.033)}
                    & {(0.221;1.567)}
                                  & {(-0.051;-0.029)}
                                                & {(-0.830;0.820)}
                                                              & {(-0.061;-0.042)}
        & {(-1.834;1.346)}
                    & {(-0.065;-0.047)}
                                  & {(-0.630;1.257)}
                                                & {(-0.057;-0.040)}
                                                              & {(-2.115;1.006)}
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
    \end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.